# How do I convert a time domain signal into frequency domain?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I am working on pedestrian step detection, I want to convert **time domain** signal into **frequency domain** with filtration. Then i want to calculate some statistical features in frequency domain such as entropy and energy. I have already calculated some in time domain. I tried to convert and filter out time domain signal into frequency domain using **FFT** and then based on **PSD**, filtered the signal and then again implemented **IFFT**. The out put i got is filtered data but when i showed it to professor, she said its not in frequency domain. I also want to use moving window of **size=200samples** and with **50% overlap** of previous window.Also interested in using **STFT**. Could some one guide me what wrong i am doing or provide any code help in matlab?
Below i am pasting the code i used and also some output result of acceleration data.

```
Fs=200;
dt = .005;
%%time=IMU_ULISS.time(:)
n = length(IMU_ULISS.time(:));
%%norm is normalized time domain signal
fhat = fft(norm,n); % Computed the fast Fourier transform
psd = fhat.*conj(fhat)/n; % Power spectrum (power per freq)
freq = 1/(dt*n)*(0:n);
L = 1:floor(n/2);
indices = psd>100; % Find all freqs with large power
psdclean = psd.*indices; % Zero out all others
fhat = indices.*fhat; % Zero out small Fourier coeffs. in Y
ffilt = ifft(fhat); % Inverse FFT for filtered time signal
figure;
plot(IMU_ULISS.time(:),norm,'r','LineWidth',1.5), hold on
plot(IMU_ULISS.time(:),ffilt,'b','LineWidth',1.2)
legend('Clean','Filtered')
figure;
plot(freq(L),psd(L),'r','LineWidth',1.5), hold on
plot(freq(L),psdclean(L),'-b','LineWidth',1.2)
legend('Noisy','Filtered')
```

[image: Texting Acceleration]
[image: Texting Acceleration]
[image: Texting Acceleration]

Comment: Applying FFT takes you to the frequency domain, applying IFFT takes you back to the time (or space) domain.

Comment: Alright, thanks. So just using this command 'fhat = fft(norm,n)', will be enough to get good frequency domain signal? Because after converting in to frequency domain i want to calculate energy and entropy features. @CrisLuengo

Comment: I don’t know what a “good frequency domain signal” is. I recommend that you read up on Fourier analysis basics before you start using functions that you don’t understand. There are no shortcuts to learning. Using functions you don’t understand leads to code you don’t understand and don’t trust. “Someone on SO said it was OK” is not an excuse I would take from any employee or student.

Comment: Alright, i red something about fft (frequency peaks in time domain) now and trying to do it, what i also came to know is, i should apply fft with a window size=10 samples with 50% overlap to previous window, so that i should not loose any useful information from my data. @CrisLuengo